# filling the attributes according to intersection of two layers (Postgresql)

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, land-cover

How to automatically fill attributes of a point layer according to the exact position in the polygon layer?

I mean how to write a command in PostgreSQL to automatically fill the attributes by the polygon layer (corine land cover) where is the point located?

Comment: I think you are looking for WHERE ST_Intersects(poly.geom, points.geom). I suggest you read up on ST_Intersects and come back if you get stuck.

Comment: You'll also want to review web resources on the `UPDATE` command syntax of SQL/PostgreSQL.